# IMediaEvent not firing any events

Tags: c++, directshow

I have capture graph with audio and video and I'm trying to detect Ctrl-Alt-Del and other similar situations where I lose the video preview. The MSDN is talking about IMediaEvent, but it never fires any events.

Does this IMediaEvent works at all? If it does, please explain how to use it, because what's described here is not functional:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390640(v=vs.85).aspx

P.S.
People usually write a kernel driver to avoid these problems, but before taking that road, I would like to see if I can do it in user mode.

Answer (score 0):

Look at EC_DISPLAY_CHANGED. And note that it is not passed to the application by default. You will need to call CancelDefaultHandling.

Comment: no, it doesn't get fired. Tried with and without default handling.

Comment: are you using a custom renderer? It's the renderer that normally raises these events.